# How to make a thread wait until a variable reaches one of a set of values in .NET/Csharp

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, system.reactive

I've written a class that has a property of type `TProperty` and an event of type `Action<TProperty>` that fires whenever that property changes.  `TProperty` is typically an enum type, but that shouldn't matter.

I'd like to create a method with signature

```
bool WaitUntilPropertyIs(int TimeoutMs, IEnumerable<TProperty> AllowedValues)
```

that blocks the thread that called it until the property changes to a value that is in `AllowedValues`.  Ofcourse if WaitUntilPropertyIs is called when the property is alread one of the `AllowedValues`, there should be no blocking.  `WaitUntilPropertyIs` should wait at most `TimeoutMs` and return false if the Timeout is exceeded (normal `AutoResetEvent.Wait` semantics).

I'm open to using Reactive Extensions or traditional synchronization constructs.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: The class I referred to in the original question has a state machine.  The property being watched is the state of the state machine.  Sometimes the operation I want to perform on the class can only be done in certain states.  So WaitUntilPropertyIs will pause the current thread until the class instance enters the appropriate state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rx is overkill for this kind of scenario. You can do it via `ManualResetEvent` or `ManualResetEventSlim`. You can pattern your solution to the following:

```
public event Action<TProperty> MyEvent;
public TProperty Prop { get; private set; }

bool WaitUntilPropertyIs(int timeout, IEnumerable<TProperty> allowedValues)
{
    var gotAllowed = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    Action<int> handler = item =>
    {
        if (allowedValues.Contains(item)) gotAllowed.Set();
    };

    try
    {
        MyEvent += handler;
        return allowedValues.Contains(Prop) || gotAllowed.Wait(timeout);
    }
    finally
    {
        MyEvent -= handler;
    }
}
```

I don't know your exact requirements though so consider modifying the code above to protect against race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

In Rx + ReactiveUI, this is accomplished via:

```
someObject.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SomeProperty)
    .Where(x => x.Value == "Something")
    .First();
```

If we wanted to add a timeout + a bool signifying that the property is actually set, we could do this:

```
bool valueIsSet = someObject.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SomeProperty)
    .Where(x => x.Value == "Something")
    .Select(x => true)
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Observable.Return(false))
    .First();
```

Comment: In the second example, you can avoid the `Catch` by using the overload of `Timeout` that takes an `other` Observable to use if the timeout is reached. `.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Observable.Return(false))`

Answer (score 1):

I decided to wrap all of this functionality in a class so I can reuse it in other places.  This code does the trick.

On the constructor, pass in CurrentValueFunc which must return the current value of the watched variable on demand, pass in IsValueAcceptableFunc which must return true if the current value is acceptable.

You need to ensure that ValueWatcher.ValueUpdated is called whenever the value changes.

```
public class ValueWatcher<TValue> : IDisposable
{
    ManualResetEvent _ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Func<TValue, bool> _isValueAcceptableFunc;

    public ValueWatcher(Func<TValue> CurrentValueFunc, Func<TValue, bool> IsValueAcceptableFunc)
    {
        _isValueAcceptableFunc = IsValueAcceptableFunc;
        ValueUpdated(CurrentValueFunc.Invoke());
    }

    public void ValueUpdated(TValue Value)
    {
        if (_isValueAcceptableFunc.Invoke(Value))
            _ev.Set();
        else
            _ev.Reset();
    }

    public bool Wait()
    {
        return _ev.WaitOne();
    }

    public bool Wait(int TimeoutMs)
    {
        return _ev.WaitOne(TimeoutMs);
    }

    public bool Wait(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return _ev.WaitOne(ts);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    void Dispose(bool Disposing)
    {
        if (Disposing)
        {
            _ev.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'Waiter' class and a list-style container should do it. Lock up the list access and the property setter/event/whatever with the same Critical Section.  The waiter class needs only the AllowedValues and an event for the callers to wait on, (OK, maybe a 'bool check(IEnumerable newAllowedValues)' helper).

That should be it.  In WaitUntilPropertyIs(), acquire the CS and check against the property values first to see if it can just release the CS and return immediately, if not, the caller has to wait.  Create a waiter, copy in the passed AllowedValues, add the waiter to the list, release the CS and wait on the event with the passed timeout. When the event wait returns, re-acquire the CS, remove the waiter from the list, dispose() it, release the CS and return with true/false from the event wait call.

In the setter/Action/whatever, acquire the CS, iterate the list, comparing with the new AllowedValues, fire any event on any waiter where the new values satisfy the range and then release the CS.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Model that property as `Behavior` (class from Rx, and a general concept in reactive programming for values that changes over a period of time).